# Share js obect between html pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have page1.html and script1.js files. When page1 is loaded script1.js creates connection with c/c++ layer and sends/receives data. Everything works fine so far.

Now I added page2.html page with script2.js that's loaded by page1.html. page2.hmtl also needs to communicate with c/c++ layer. For that I am trying to reuse existing connection from script1.js
Does that make any sense what I am trying to do? If yes, then how? Or do I have to reopen connection with c layer again when page2 is loaded?

So far what I tried to do is created shared.js file and tried to share same connection between 2 html pages. But failing due to inability to share js objects between html pages. (I.e. connection information is reset when page2 is loaded. I tried localstorage, but it is only for string storage) 
I supposed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621015/pass-javascript-objects-between-html-pages) is similar to my case, but its solution was not completely clear to me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++.  The fact that the other end of the connection is written in C++ is irrelevant.  Please remove the tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In fact, you can use localStorage or sessionStorage to share object between pages but you should process it by JSON.stringify method to convert to a string and JSON.parse to restore an object from a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here. Since you haven't shared any piece of code, my answer will be based on a guess. One option is creating a wrapper html file and include your js files in it. Then load your secondary pages with XMLHTTP request ( ajax ) so you don't reload the entire page, and your js files instance will persists on either page. Another option is you said some kind of connection, so if that is an object you can take a look localStorage/sessionStorage on browser to keep data on browser while pages are changing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have solved my problem with suggestion option 1, i.e. by loading 2nd html into 1st one.